# TAPI 2.2 event notification manner problem

Tags: c++, tapi, caller-id

I have a technical issue and kindly wish to help me.
I have developed a console application sample to catch a caller ID using TAPI 2.2.
I have faced a problem with some modem drivers (not all), I can’t catch the caller ID.

My objective is to use the TAPI to monitor caller ID only, I don’t need it to make calls or other media capabilities.

My code use TAPI event notification manner (LINEINITIALIZEEXOPTION_USEEVENT) and run thread to monitor this event as:

```
while (true) {
        switch (WaitForSingleObject((HANDLE)(pLine->m_hLineEvent), 1000))
        {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                pLine->ProcessEvent();
        case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
            break;
        default: continue;
        }
}
```

The exact problem is a m_hLineEvent event member doesn’t get any object by the TAPI library, so the while always timeout, but everything ok and my program runs well when I run external software like (Advanced caller id, smartcallmonitor, …etc.) !!! “I don’t expect this software set object manually and my application catch it, as I know the TAPI will set it automatically when calling info available”.

Does any help please?
Note: My full program code available at:
[TAPI Samble](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14J5Qa1MfzqkLk0rukj5K22-HCWRIWsbA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Are modems still a thing? TAPI 2.x is at least 20 years old.

Comment: like POS systems may use a modem device to detect caller id